# How to move div to extreme right in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am customise wordpress theme named "Flexible". I have add phone no in header section and want to float it right side. But the unable to do even I did inline css. Here you go: [www.dbsmiles.net](http://www.dbsmiles.net).

Please let me know where i am wrong. Thanks

Here is my code :

```html
<div class="phone" style="margin-top: 10px; 
                clear: right; 
                float: right; 
                margin-right">
  <p style="font-weight: 600; 
                  font-size: 42px; 
                  color: rgb(52, 123, 98); 
                  text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">Call Us Today</p>
  <br/>
  <p style="font-weight: 600; 
                  font-size: 42px; 
                  color: #D1D341; 
                  text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">954-320-0110</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is my code : <div class="phone" style="  margin-top: 10px; clear: right;
 float: right;
 margin-right
"><p style="font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: rgb(52, 123, 98);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">Call Us Today</p><br/><p style="font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #D1D341;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">954-320-0110</p></div>

Comment: Hi , Thanks for edit but my problem is still there . please see the link : http://www.dbsmiles.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is caused by the outer `<h1 id="logo">` - that one is not wide enough to let your `div` float to the outer right. You might try moving your `div` into the `header` element and re-style parts of the header.

Or you can use `position: absolute; right: 0px` for your div like this:

```html
<div style="margin-top: 10px; position: absolute; right:0;" class="phone">
  <p style="font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: rgb(52, 123, 98);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">Call Us Today</p>
  <br>
  <p style="font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #D1D341;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #C5C5C5;">954-320-0110</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @dhh .You made my day :)

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Comment: Hi dhh ! 1 more query please . it is now showing in iphone 6 plus . Please advice what should i do ?